# Using MySQL, I want to SELECTmultiple columns and use GROUP BY but only show the grouped by column once per grouping

Tags: mysql

At present, a column the the rows are grouped by is displayed for each row. I want to only display the column when the grouping changes.

eg:

```
water  sea
       ocean
       river
sand   beach
       desert
trees  woods
       forest
```

Comment: sorry - the listing did not come out right.

Comment: Don't do this using SQL. Process the dataset on the client instead.

Comment: water is the group by column for sea, ocean, river data - sand is the group by column for beach and desert - trees is the group by column for woods and forest.

Comment: Hi Giorgios - I am sending the query via PHP and could manage it there but I felt I might be missing a simpler way with SQL

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it in MySQL, here is what you can do:

```
select your_column1, group_concat(distinct your_column2 separator '\n') from your_table 
group by your_column1;
```

From

```
your_column1 | your_column2
----------------------------
water        | sea
----------------------------
water        | ocean
----------------------------
water        | river
----------------------------
sand         | beach
----------------------------
sand         | desert
----------------------------
trees        | woods
----------------------------
trees        | forest
```

To

```
your_column1 | your_column2
----------------------------
water        | sea
             | ocean
             | river
----------------------------
sand         | beach
             | desert
----------------------------
trees        | woods
             | forest
```